# What is it? sampling variance OR sampling variance of the mean

Tags: variance, sampling, mean, sample

I got confused about some terms! I have group of studies that measure a parameter X in certain group of subjects. Each study used certain number of subjects `N` and reported a `MEAN` and `VARIANCE` of parameter X. Like this:

```
Study   N    MEAN    VARIANCE
1       10   5       0.6
2       20   6       0.8
```

Do we call `VARIANCE` reported "the sampling variance" or is it called the "sampling variance of the mean"?

Comment: It might be neither.  Quite possibly "VARIANCE" refers to the variance of the data.  *How do the studies describe this statistic?*

Comment: @whuber they describe it as (MEAN+- SD). I calculated variance then as SD^2. So, yes variance here refers to the variance of the measured data in each study.

Comment: so is it considered as sampling variance? or can we call it sampling variance of the mean value reported?